# SQL Server - Invalid Argument Supplied

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection, connection-string, windows-update

So we have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express running on a local server, and a bunch of machines on the same LAN use a program I wrote in C# to access said server.

All the machines in the building except one can connect quite happily.

Connection string is:

`Data Source=[IP address here],53535\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS_Main;;User ID=EMSUser;Password=[password here];`

Exact error message is:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An invalid argument was supplied.)"

Struggling to believe the 'invalid argument' bit, given that all other machines connect quite happily.

SQSL is definitely configured to accept remote connections, instance name is definitely correct.

The problem machine can connect using SQLSMS, but not via C#.

Disabling firewall on the problem machine makes no difference.

Everything seems to have been working fine on the problem machine up until a Windows 10 update a couple of days ago.

EDIT: An update on this: I now have two machines with this issue, and they both seem to have only developed it after Windows 10 updated to version 1803. All the pre-1803 machines still work fine.

Can anyone shed any more light on this please?

Comment: I *assume* youve checked the logs? What did they say?

Comment: Nothing other than "starting up database", "server resumed execution after being idle", and backup messages. Oh and a couple of "Recovery completed" messages.

Comment: Then the connection isn't hitting the server; which sounds like it is the firewall, the connection details are wrong, or similar connection related issue.

Comment: As I said, disabling the firewall does not make any difference, and all the connection details appear to be correct because they work on other machines.

Comment: Your connection string is effed up. You should choose the approach you want to use for identifying the instance and be consistent. Lucky isn't working. To connect by IP,port, you don't (and shouldn't) supply the instance name. And what is the purpose of doubled semi-colons? That is what the port number does. More examples [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: I've now corrected that, but the problem persists. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else hitting this issue, I discovered that this was happening because the client application was being run from a shared drive, and Windows 10 update 1803 must have some security update in it that causes this problem (only machines running 1803 were affected).

Running the application from the machine's hard drive solved the problem.

I'd still like to know a technical explanation for this, even though the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. A dig deeper and discovered that this happened after installing an update (May 8, 2018—KB4103721).  Try to uninstall this update or use named pipes instead tcp.

Comment: June 26, 2018—KB4284848 (OS Build 17134.137)

This patch released today fixed the issue on my system running a shared executable SQL program