# SQL Server does not exist or access denied, but only for some users

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, networking

I'm running into a frustrating problem with a subset of users. I've got a small client application that runs on their local machine and throws an error when trying to connect to a remote database server.

Here's the error and what I know:

> [DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

1. There are lots and lots of other instances of this I've searched through, but all of the ones I've found point to a server-side issue (not running, firewall blocking port 1433, etc.). In my case, the problem is only occurring on a subset of users systems, so I have to assume it is something specific to their systems.
2. Credentials for the SQL Server are using a service account, so it's the same for all users, ruling out some users being properly set up but not others
3. When the error occurs, the response takes a long time to come back, which would lead me to think that the error is related to a timeout and not denied access (this might be a bad assumption)
4. The error occurs no matter whether I use `OleDBConnection` or `ODBCConnection`
5. The error occurs if I use a connection string built on the fly or a DSN I created.  The DSN points to the same SQL server that I can't connect to via my application and uses the same {SQL Server} driver.  I've also tried it using the SQL server native client 11 and get the same issue.
6. I can create a user DSN on their machine and successfully test the connection to the server with it
7. I can use the user DSN to link a table on the remote server in a Microsoft Access database on their machine and that works.
8. I compiled my code 64 bit only as well as trying 32 bit to see if anything helped.  It did not.

I'd assume it has to be something in my code, except it works for multiple other users. So some combo of my code plus their system configuration has to be at play, right?

Here's the entirety of the connection logic:

```
dim DBConnection as OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection()

DBConnection.ConnectionString = "DSN=<DSN name>;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>"

DBConnection.Open()
```

It times out on the `DBConnection.Open()`. I looked at the ODBC trace logs comparing my own system's trace to theirs, and it looks identical up until the point where I get a successful connection back and they get a timeout.

Any thoughts? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Your point #1 is most likely the cause (port 1433 is blocked), but this is on the **client side**, not the server. Chances are, they are running firewall software (such as Windows Firewall) that is blocking outbound SQL Server connections.
If it's Windows Firewall, there is a built-in wizard that will allow you to allow outbound SQL Server connections.

Regarding this:

> When the error occurs, the response takes a long time to come back, which would lead me to think that the error is related to a timeout and not denied access (this might be a bad assumption)

When the server address can't be found or can't be connected to, most of the time, the client will take a while before throwing the "connection" error. It won't throw the error immediately.

Other possibilities:

- VPN
- Server name vs IP address - I've had users that could NOT ever connect to a SQL Server box using the server name, because of various network configuration issues, either on their devices or because of network configurations at their location. Try using the IP address (or vice versa).

Comment: I had wondered about that, but then why does creating a DSN and testing it work or using that DSN to link a table in Microsoft access (#6 and #7 of my experiments)?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear.  I made a DSN which pointed to the same SQL server that I can't connect to through my program.  So the DSN is pointing to a remote SQL server.  When I use that DSN with access (as a linked table in access) it works, but when I use the DSN with my app, it times out.

Comment: That DSN issue could be a permissions problem to the DSN itself. Is it a machine DSN or user DSN?

Comment: @AdamSchwartz, I would start over with a new connection string, to make sure you have it correct.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

And I would avoid ODBC, if at all possible. It is very problematic. A SQL Server native driver is more reliable.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a user DSN.  Unfortunately I don't have admin rights on the machine to create a machine DSN.  I did also try OleDB because I had read similar concerns about using ODBC, but had no luck with that either unfortunately.  I'll definitely try a connection string from scratch just to see what happens.

Comment: No luck with the new connection string test unfortunately.  Additional ideas appreciated, and thank you for the input!

Comment: What is the authentication mode of your SQL Server? Mixed mode or Windows Authentication? Are you using Named Pipes or TCP IP? Also, show us your connection string using SqlClient.SqlConnection.

Comment: I like your IP idea. Several years ago working with the IT guy to get me connected to their Sql Server, no joy. Finally tried IP and it worked. Never did find out why.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips.  I tried two new experiments this morning.  One, I switched to SqlClient from ODBC.  Second, I tried using the ip address and port option.  Both changes worked on my computer (so I know they're functional) but failed on the users system with the same timeout error.  connection string 1 was "Server=<servername\instance>;Database=<database>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>"  connection string 2 was "Server=<ip address,port>;Database=<database>;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>".  Authentication is with a sql server specific login, not windows auth.

Comment: Well, no definitive answers yet, but I did find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348869/sql-server-invalid-argument-supplied this article based on the slightly different error message that using SqlClient returned.  This proposed I needed to copy the executable to the local drive and run it, but when I tried that experiment a corporate-installed tool blocked the program from running, so I think I might be on to something.

Comment: @AdamSchwartz, what kind of installer are you using for your app? Are you simply copying over the /bin files? Or did you create an installer in VS? If you create a ClickOnce installer (the "Publish" tab in the VS project properties page), it will actually install your app into a safe sandbox location within the user's personal folders. This can help bypass some security obstacles that may exist on the user's device, because Microsoft recognizes it as a trusted app.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't tried that.  No installer, just copying the binaries to a shared location.  I may be at the point where I require IT's formal help if I want to do an install.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll probably never get a clear answer on what was happening.  I ended up rewriting the whole thing in VBA using Excel to house the code (yuk, I know).  Users who were having issues with my code could use the ADO connection I created in excel without issue which ruled out ports being blocked.  I appreciate the input from you all!